# Address already in Use error in H2 server mode

Tags: java, database, h2

Just started learning H2 database. It is said that if H2 database is opened in server mode, multiple VMs can be connected. Is that tcp sever has to be started only once? If it is so, Consider an exapmle of two or more VMs accessing same databse, first VM starts the TCP server, connected to db and it works fine, simultaneously if I connect to the same database from second VM I am getting address already in use error. What have to be done?

Here is my sample Code

FirstVm.java

```
    Server server = Server.createTcpServer(
                      new String[] { "-tcpPort", "9123", "-tcpAllowOthers" }).start();

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://10.67.445.91:9123/mem:stackoverflow;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "sa", "");
```

SecondVm.java

```
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://10.67.445.91:9123/mem:stackoverflow;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "sa", "");
```

Comment: Is the second VM also trying to start the server?

Comment: No its not starting the server. Only first VM starting the server and only once.

Comment: Works for me. Please provide an [mcve]